# automatic library update in the project

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven in the project and there was a need for one of the libraries to update automatically. I am using [this plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/), unfortunately it has a vulnerability, so I am looking for an alternative.

For example, what I want to achieve:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> abcd </groupId>
    <artifactId> xyz </artifactId>
    <version> 1.0.1 </version>
</dependency>
```

I would like it to update automatically only when the last digit is raised. e.g. up to 1.0.2, 1.0.3 etc.
If you upgrade to version 1.1.0, the automatic update will not be performed.

Comment: What kind of vulnerability? Furthermore what have you tried so far?

Comment: CVE-2020-15250 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/versions-maven-plugin/2.8.1

Comment: And where is the relationship to the plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [maven version ranges](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN402) to achieve this.  For the equivalent of `1.0.*`, use a version range of `[1.0.1,1.1-SNAPSHOT)`.  That being said, I'd use this somewhat sparingly with dependencies that you don't control, as they may change version scheme and/or functionality in ways you don't expect.  Something like [renovate](https://docs.renovatebot.com/) or [dependabot](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/about-dependabot-version-updates) may do what you need in a safer way by automating upgrade PRs that you can test before blindly accepting upgrades.